# Clear event hub for consumers after load testing

Tags: azure-eventhub

I'm load testing and ingestion app of which part sends data to event hub.

During this time, I disable the consuming azure functions, as I'm not currently testing that part of the system and don't wish to pay for them.

I then wish to test the consuming azure functions, but there is a huge backlog of item in the event hub.

I understand that it's a log and after the retention period it will be cleared.

But I'm hoping for a more immediate option, I do not to "delete" the messages per say just informing the consuming group it doesn't need to read those messages.

A few quick hacks I have tried is reducing the retention period down to 1 and disabling the event hub and re-enabling.

Searching people say event hubs cannot be cleared, I suspect one option is regarding check points however I am open to alternatives (it being a dev environment means easier albeit more drastic techniques can be adopted). This is separate to specific questions regarding check pointing even if that is the answer, as I wish to highlight a "clearing" technique.

Comment: n.b. I could in theory not use event hub and simply stub the http endpoint, but I wish to in this scenario as I'm diagnosing bottle necks.

Comment: Have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562337/1171619)

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail, happy for you to link to that answer as a possible answer to this question for a +1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the Azure Function Event Hub trigger starting checkpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47558739/can-i-change-the-azure-function-event-hub-trigger-starting-checkpoint)